# flexbox box-ordinal-group on table cells

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm attempting to reorder table cells using flexbox and box-ordinal-group (use case: a different order via a media query on mobile for a particular table without duplicating code).

I'd have thought that setting the table cells to `display: block` and the table to `display: flex` (and the various vendor-prefixed versions) would do the trick, but no such luck.

I'm wondering if it's the `tr`/`tbody` around the `td`s that's breaking out of the flexbox.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell1">Cell 1</td>
        <td class="cell2">Cell 2</td>
        <td class="cell3">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
table {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

td {
    display: block;
}

.cell1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
```

Here's an example showing it work on a `display: table`ed `<div>` but not the `<table>`. Unfortunately, I can't just use the divs as I have to support IE7...

http://jsfiddle.net/GTL4e/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex items *must* be children of flex containers, so yes, the td element is breaking things for you.  Just switch the styles you have associated with the table element to the tr element and you're good to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/GTL4e/1/

```
tr {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Also, order is not exactly the same as flex-order.  The order property begins indexing with 0, while the box-ordinal-group property begins indexing with 1.

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. I'm looking to reorder cells across multiple rows, so I'm going to have to find another solution. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: Yeah, the elements have to be siblings if you want to reorder them.